call_async times out when spin_until_future_complete times out although service runs successfully
I have writen a custome service. The service successfully runs when called from bash or a simpler node with an call_async and spin_until_future_complete. However in my statemaschine, whenever it is called, it will time out, even though the services bash logs indicate it running successfully
My logs for the statemaschine
[INFO] [1726147909.911237747] [state_machine_node]: Waiting for /pixelToPose service to be available...
[INFO] [1726147909.911642859] [state_machine_node]: Service availible
[INFO] [1726147910.918833881] [state_machine_node]: Current state: INITIAL
[INFO] [1726147910.920208140] [state_machine_node]: State is INITIAL. Calling /pixelToPose service.
[INFO] [1726147910.921598422] [state_machine_node]: Attempting to call /pixelToPose service.
[INFO] [1726147910.923029870] [state_machine_node]: Service available. Preparing request.
[INFO] [1726147910.924569273] [state_machine_node]: Sending request to /pixelToPose service.
[ERROR] [1726147920.927116325] [state_machine_node]: Service call failed: No result received

The statemaschine code (with not relevant states removed)
from rclpy.node import Node
from tutorial_interfaces.srv import PixelTooPose
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from nav2_msgs.action import NavigateToPose
from rclpy.action import ActionClient

class StateMachineNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('state_machine_node')
        self.state = 'INITIAL'
        self.client = self.create_client(PixelTooPose, '/pixelToPose')
        self.get_logger().info('Waiting for /pixelToPose service to be available...')
        if not self.client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=10.0):
            self.get_logger().error('/pixelToPose service not available')
            return
        else:
            self.get_logger().info('Service availible')
        
        #self.action_client = ActionClient(self, NavigateToPose, 'navigate_to_pose')

        # Create a timer to periodically call the timer_callback method
        self.timer = self.create_timer(1.0, self.timer_callback)
        self.poses = []

    def timer_callback(self):
        self.get_logger().info(f'Current state: {self.state}')
        
        if self.state == 'INITIAL':
            self.get_logger().info('State is INITIAL. Calling /pixelToPose service.')
            self.call_pixel_to_pose_service()
        elif self.state == 'NAVIGATE':
            self.get_logger().info('State is NAVIGATE. Navigating to poses.')
            self.navigate_to_poses()
        else:
            self.get_logger().error(f'Unknown state: {self.state}')

    def call_pixel_to_pose_service(self):
        self.get_logger().info('Attempting to call /pixelToPose service.')

        if not self.client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=10.0):
            self.get_logger().error('/pixelToPose service not available')
            self.state = 'INITIAL'
            return

        self.get_logger().info('Service available. Preparing request.')

        request = PixelTooPose.Request()
        request.x_coordinates = [1.2, 2.1]
        request.y_coordinates = [0.2, 0.8]
        request.best_percentage = 80.0
        request.height = 108
        request.width = 90

        self.get_logger().info('Sending request to /pixelToPose service.')
        future = self.client.call_async(request)
        self.get_logger().info('call_async.')
        
        try:
            rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, future, timeout_sec=10.0)
            if future.result() is not None:
                response = future.result()
                self.poses = response.poses
                self.get_logger().info(f'Received {len(self.poses)} poses.')
                for idx, pose in enumerate(self.poses):
                    self.get_logger().info(f'Pose {idx}: Position(x={pose.pose.position.x}, y={pose.pose.position.y}, z={pose.pose.position.z}), Orientation(x={pose.pose.orientation.x}, y={pose.pose.orientation.y}, z={pose.pose.orientation.z}, w={pose.pose.orientation.w})')
                self.state = 'NAVIGATE'
            else:
                self.get_logger().error('Service call failed: No result received')
                self.state = 'INITIAL'
        except Exception as e:
            self.get_logger().error(f'Exception during service call: {str(e)}')
            self.state = 'INITIAL'

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = StateMachineNode()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I successfully manage to get line 57 to log on the console
self.get_logger().info('call_async.')
The service then runs almost instantly
however nothing happens until I the call times out and I get line 69
self.get_logger().error('Service call failed: No result received')
I would be realy greatfull if someone can tell me why I am not recieving the return data, and idealy a fix. From my own testing so far the service pixelToPose works, as it will return a valid response when called from bash console or through a simpler node.
edit: I moved the service call to the init portion were it worked, and then to the begining of the timer_callback were it failed in the same way.
